# How does Microsoft Calculator, calculate such large numbers?

Tags: c++, numbers, calculator

I am up to about 8E10000 so how is it calculating such large number, there is no variable that can hold such large numbers.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/25/141253.aspx for some details.

Answer (score 0):

Normal types in C can usually only store up to 64 bits, instead of a single variable, you can use an array of characters to store digits of your number and write functions for each operation (sum, minus and so on) in your program.

You may look at this:  [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In a nut shell they aren't using one variable to hold the operands but data structures than can probably hold arbitrary long numbers (like an array) and they evaluate operations by considering the number to be in a large [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) system.

When you actually do a math operation the operands aren't variables but array (or any other data structure that is suitable) and you do it by doing the operation (where available) component wise.

When you want to add 2 array you choose a radix and then loop the arrays and add op1[i] to op2[i] then you take that value and check to see if it its bigger than your radix and compute a carriage that you add to next addition.

```
car = (op1[i] + op2[i])%radix
```

You need to be careful in choosing the radix and the underlaying data so an addition doesn't cause an overflow.

This how you also do when you add numbers in the base 10 by hand but without taking into account the radix.

You can also look over [this](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) for a bigint package.